# salt-stack: capture group for regex include_pat

Tags: salt

is it possible to have a capture group with include_pat when copying files ?

I would like to do something like that:

```
copy_template:
    file.recurse:
    - name: '{{ service_path }}\$1'
    - template: jinja
    - include_pat: E@^(.*)\.template$
    - source: {{ pillar['locations']['systemtoolsfolder'] }}\
```

Answer (score 2):

A capture group is a [type of backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Saltstack, being python based, [uses the re.match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do regular expression matching, which [appears to support backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163092/python-regex-backreference-a-matching-regex-group), so these backreferences are allowed.

However, you be unable to pass the value of the backreference `\1` in the `- include_pat` field back to `- name` because the `- name` field is never processed by the `re.match` object. Even if it were, variable scope would prevent you from sharing the backreference between `re.match` calls.

Instead, you will need to do one of the following:

- Rename all the files in `- source` from `myfile.conf.template` to `myfile.conf`
- Use cmd.run to do a [batch](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk/) file [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd) after your `file.recurse` and add to your `file.recurse` an [onchanges](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onchanges) pointed to a previous event in order to defeat the idempotency (that is, to prevent it from writing out the .template files every time salt runs). You will also be sure to use a [require](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require) and `onchanges` in your cmd.run that references `copy_template`

  This will have the unfortunate side-effect that you will never be able to update your jinja templates. You will only be able to deploy them the first time - at least not without first deleting what is there, and then re-writing and re-copying from the source.
- Use `file.managed` for every template file.

For example:

```
copy_template1:
  file.managed:
    - name: '{{ service_path }}\template1.conf'
    - template: jinja
    - source: {{ pillar['locations']['systemtoolsfolder'] }}\template1.conf.template
copy_template2:
  file.managed:
    - name: '{{ service_path }}\template2.conf'
    - template: jinja
    - source: {{ pillar['locations']['systemtoolsfolder'] }}\template2.conf.template
...
and so forth
```

Comment: {{ service_path }} is just a path. In my case minion is on windows so for example c:\myservice\.

I just wanted all .template files from source to be copy without the extension .template but so keep the base filename.

for example : myfile.conf.template to become myfile.conf

Comment: You should add this to your original question to help clarify it, ping me or flag it for moderator to reopen once done.